# "no matching architecture in universal wrapper", but file has it

Tags: ios, xcode

Note: There are a lot of SO questions with a similar problem, but almost all of them have an issue running in the Simulator because they failed to build universal libraries. In this case, I have a universal library, I just can't figure out why the device loader doesn't like the architecture in the wrapper.

We build some C++ code that uses Tensorflow Lite on multiple platforms. I'm trying to link it into our iOS build. I created a universal shared library with a couple of shared libraries built by that team. They build them as individual shared libraries with one architecture per file (one for macOS, one for iOS arm64, and one for iOS x86). I put the two iOS files together using lipo, and I was able to link and run in the Simulator. Unfortunately, I can't exercise that code path in the Simulator (for other reasons), so I built and ran on a device.

But when I try to run on a device, I get

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libtensorflowlite.so  
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E3E3B0E9-B36E-4ADB-9FFC-CA2D6D2A8AC8/MyApp.app/MyApp  
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:  
  /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E3E3B0E9-B36E-4ADB-9FFC-CA2D6D2A8AC8/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libtensorflowlite.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

I know the App Store doesn't like x86 bits in universal shared libraries, so I used lipo in an Xcode build phase to remove the x86 part, and now my file looks like:

```
$ file /Users/rmann/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fdskkibuvbsubudkmqtgsjxmyqme/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libtensorflowlite.so  
/Users/rmann/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fdskkibuvbsubudkmqtgsjxmyqme/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libtensorflowlite.so: Mach-O universal binary with 1 architecture: [arm64:Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64]  
/Users/rmann/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fdskkibuvbsubudkmqtgsjxmyqme/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libtensorflowlite.so (for architecture arm64): Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64
```

But it still doesn't see it.

I do something similar with another library we get from a third party, and everything works fine. How can I inspect this further to determine what the issue is? Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of `lipo -info libtensorflowlite.so`  ?

Comment: `$ lipo -info libtensorflowlite.so
Architectures in the fat file:libtensorflowlite.so are: x86_64 arm64`

Comment: Your `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATH` is set with `@executable_path`?

Comment: If you were able to use the simulator, I would suggest to use otool...

Comment: It’s clearly able to find it. It works in the simulator.